# php ajax msql jquery zend framework

Tags: php

I'm using the Zend framework (php) and MySQL. My table named fruit has 2 columns. Name and Origin. I have a dropdown list for Name and based on whichever value the user selects, the 2nd dropdown for Origin would be populated after quering the database.

**The Model**

```
<?php
    class Application_Model_fruit extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {
        public function getname($origin)
        {
            $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $select = "SELECT Name FROM fruit where origin = $origin";
            $stmt = $db->query($select);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

**The Controller**

```
<?php
    class fruitController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {
        private $_db;
        private $info;

        public function init()
        {
            $this->_db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
            $this->info = new Application_Model_fruit();
        }

        public function nameAction()
        {
            $origin=$this->getRequest()->getParam('Origin');
            echo $data = $this->info->getname($origin);
        }
    }
?>
```

**The .phtml**

```
<div>
    Name:
    <select id="name">
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="1">Orange</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div>
    Origin:
    <select id="origin">
    </select>
</div>
```

**The Ajax/Jquery**

```
<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#name").change(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "<?php echo SITE_URL;?>fruit/name",
                data:"Name="+$("#name").val(),

                success:function(ret){
                    $("#origin").val(ret);
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Could somebody please help me? I don't get any output in the 2nd dropdown list.

Comment: Contender for "best ever question title".

Comment: Well the way your using the Zend_Table is incorrect

Comment: apple and orange are having the same val

Comment: Should you be using `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Answer (score 2):

Your server script must be

```
public function nameAction()
{
   $origin=$this->getRequest()->getParam('Name');

....
```

also protect your database from from sql injection

```
$select = "SELECT Name FROM fruit where origin =?";
    $stmt = $db->query(
                 $select,
                array($orgin)
            );
```

also HTML `select` must have different value

```
<select id="name">
 <option value="1">Apple</option>
 <option value="2">Orange</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: While the first snippet is not true I believe the second addresses the problem, see my post also to properly build your query to protect yourself from injection. Remove the first snippet (data can be a string in this format based on jquery's ajax documentation) and I will upvote

Comment: @Orangepill i have removed the snippets thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

Since orgin is an integer this does not solve the core problem but not doing this will leave you wide open for SQL injection.  This should be used as part of a more comprehensive solution.

You problem is that your $orgin is not surrounded in quotes or escaped/sanitized in any way.

Use Zend_Db_Adapter's quote function to escape and sanitize your data.

```
$select = "SELECT Name FROM fruit where origin = ".$db->quote($orgin);
```

Comment: origin is an integer. Its not the problem.